# How to override template Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Qty

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.7

I have no luck overriding template Magento_Sales::items/column/qty.phtml in my custom module like so:

file
`app/code/Maghos/Backorders/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="column_qty">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Maghos_Backorders::items/column/qty.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

After cache flush Magento is still loading this vendor file:
`vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/qty.phtml`
instead of my custom `Maghos/Backorders/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/qty.phtml`.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<update handle="sales_order_transactions_grid_block"/>` `<update handle="sales_order_item_price"/>` and remove `translate="true"` attribute from argument then `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. It's still loading vendor file.

Comment: Try to add 
`<update handle="sales_order_transactions_grid_block"/>`
   `<update handle="sales_order_item_price"/>`
and remove  `translate="true"`  attribute from argument
then `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: Still no luck. If I comment out this line in vendor **sales_order_view.xml** : `<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Qty" name="column_qty" template="Maghos_Backorders::items/column/qty.phtml" group="column"/>` my custom phtml renders. So I thinkg there is a problem in my `action method="setTemplate"` declaration.